# how to list the schedule for active BPs?

Tags: nodeos, block-producer, cleos, schedule

anyone knows a command to list the current schedule for the active BPs?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in 2 steps:

## 1. **Find the latest block**

This can be done using the `get_info()` end-point. Example:

`$ curl http://publicapi-mainnet.eosauthority.com/v1/chain/get_info`

and save `head_block_id` (e.g. `0064aed8bf489f860ea6897f36fcd0ca3d60c0364479afc6259e7262d7bd200b`)

## 2. **Check the header of the latest block**

```
    curl --request POST \
         --url http://publicapi-mainnet.eosauthority.com/v1/chain/get_block_header_state \  
         --data '{"block_num_or_id":"0064aed8bf489f860ea6897f36fcd0ca3d60c0364479afc6259e7262d7bd200b"}'
```

and look for the `active_schedule` key. It should look something like this:

```
>>> response['active_schedule']
{'version': 162, 'producers': [{'producer_name': 'argentinaeos', 'block_signing_key': 'EOS7jq4FHrFrtCXxpRQ39dBeDMa5AjM4VaRbqBECkSa5aZnizJzrx'}, {'producer_name': 'bitfinexeos1', 'block_signing_key': 'EOS6sgKjHUFtY1XxxQaMDwfxBac6nDBibVzZHb8LFMVmvSjcCdDhE'}, {'producer_name': 'cypherglasss', 'block_signing_key': 'EOS5rTrUiqvgu7YCVyKCeQ1QXA7Uo94FZhq7zKcNPqbrCP5u5fQXo'}, {'producer_name': 'eos42freedom', 'block_signing_key': 'EOS4tw7vH62TcV
tMgm2tjXzn9hTuHEBbGPUK2eos42ssY7ip4LTzu'}, ...
```

Comment: second url should be

curl --request POST --url http://publicapi-mainnet.eosauthority.com/v1/chain/get_block_header_state --data '{"block_num_or_id":"0082587fb060f5f10f270065e8b3a29932819f4f8819f03085899f296d8bfe07"}'

the one from the provided answer is missing "v1/chain"

other than that it is a perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
cleos get schedule
```